# continuity and countability

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For $n>1$, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there are at most two values in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f^{-1}(x)$ is non-empty and countable.

I know $\mathbb{R}^n-A$ is path-connected if $A$ is countable. Will that help in this question?

Comment: does not $f(x)=0$ contradict it?

Comment: @Gio: no, it doesn't, because there are no points where the image is nonempty and countable. To the OP: think about what the image of $f$ should be. Can you find (up to) two special values associated with this image?

Comment: Given that $\mathbb{R}^n-A$ is path connected if $A$ is countable, one way of proving the result is: let $x$ be a value such that $f^{-1}(x)$ is countable. Then $A=\mathbb{R}^n-f^{-1}(x)$ is path connected ,and thus $f(A)$ is path connected and thus it's an interval, not containing $x$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

José Carlos Santos proved that the result is not true if $n=1$: just take $f(x)=x$. It is, however, true if $n\ge 2$. To prove it, let $a<b$ be two values such that $f^{-1}(a), f^{-1}(b)$ is non-empty and countable. In particular, let $\alpha,\beta:f(\alpha)=a,f(\beta)=b$

Now, let $\Gamma$ be the (uncountable) set of continuos paths such that $\gamma(0)=\alpha, \gamma(1)=\beta$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f\circ \gamma$ is continuos, and as such $f\circ\gamma([0,1])$ will be a connected set. Since the only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals and $a,b\in f\circ\gamma([0,1])$, $f\circ\gamma([0,1])\supset [a,b]$.

We can take an uncountable subset $\Delta$ of $\Gamma$ made of paths that intersect only at $\alpha,\beta$.It is then easy to see that,
$$\forall x\in(a,b) \forall \delta\in \Delta\exists x^*_\delta\in\delta((0,1)):f(x^*)=x$$
Since $\delta$ are non intersecting,  $x^*_\delta$ will be different for every $\delta$, and so $f^{-1}(x)\supset \{x^*_\delta\}$ is uncountable.

Thus, every other value $c$ satisfying the required property cannot be contained in the interval $[a,b]$. Let now $c$ be another such value: if $c>b, b\in [a,c]$, and we have a contradiction. Similarly if $c<a, a\in [c,b]$.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how we take the $\Delta$?

Comment: Another question: where do you use the fact that $f^{-1}(a)$ is countable?

Comment: @Ravel In the final contradiction we use countability

Comment: @Ravel Take two points in $\R^n$. Are you able to find a non-countable family of non-intersecting curves?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I am still confused about one thing: when you prove that any $c$ with countable inverse cannot be contained in $[a,b]$, you do not use the fact that $a$ and $b$ have countable inverse (maybe I didn't see it). Does that imply: there cannot be a value with countable inverse in any interval?

Comment: Oh, so does that imply only the mimimum/maximum can have the countable inverse?

Comment: @Ravel Indeed one does not need the countability hypothesis until the very end: the only point that needs it is when we consider $c\not\in[a,b]$: if such a point has non-empty counter image, by the previous argument every point in the interval $(c,b)$ (or$ (a,c)$) must have uncountable counterimage, and this contradicts the countability of $f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(b)$

Comment: Note that the same argument shows that only the global maximum or minimum (if it exists) can satisfy the countability requirement. As another corollary, one gets that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic for $n\ge 2$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove it since it is false. Suppose that $n=1$ and that $f(x)=x\sin(x)$. Then, for *every* $x\in\Bbb R$, $f^{-1}(x)$ is non-empty and countable.

Comment: $x$ is also a counterexample

Comment: @Caffeine Sure, but there was a real possibility that, as far as the OP is concerned, “countable” means that it has the same cardinal as $\Bbb N$. (BTW, +1).